# R: Replace 0 with another value from another vector of values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame of student project choices in a columns called choice_1 and choice_2 but some entries are 0, which mean they didn't chose a second option.

```
df<-data.frame(studentID=c(102,103,104), choice_1=c(699,500,750),choice_2=c(698,0,0))
```

I have a data.frame of all possible choices:

```
choices<-data.frame(choices=seq(600:800)).
```

I would like to fill in the 0s in choice_1 or choice_2 based on any value in the data.frame `choices`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're hoping to do it for one *or more* `choice_*` columns, then:

```r
set.seed(42)
df[,-1] <- lapply(df[,-1], function(z) {
  z[z==0] <- sample(choices$choices, size = sum(z == 0), replace = TRUE)
  z
})
df
#   studentID choice_1 choice_2
# 1       102      699      698
# 2       103      500       49
# 3       104      750       65
```

In dplyr-ese:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("choice_"),
    ~ if_else(. == 0, as.numeric(sample(choices$choices, size = n(), replace = TRUE)), .)
    )
  )
#   studentID choice_1 choice_2
# 1       102      699      698
# 2       103      500       49
# 3       104      750       65
```

The reason for `as.numeric` is because `if_else` strictly enforces class, and while `choice_*` are `numeric`, your `choices$choices` is `integer`, so `if_else` complains. An alternative is to replace `if_else` with `ifelse` (and remove the `as.numeric`), since `base::ifelse` is a bit sloppier in that regard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and multiple options. Both are fast too!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df[df == 0] <- sample(choices$choices, length(df[df == 0]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Austin. I think I should have said that potentially the projects might not be consecutive (as someone may have withdrawn a project choice).

Answer (score 1):

We could use `across` with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("choice"), ~ifelse(.==0, sample(choices$choices), .)))
```

```
  studentID choice_1 choice_2
1       102      699      698
2       103      500       48
3       104      750      179
```